# I am stuck on this homework question (Formal Logic class w/ Fitch) my proofs are messed up in the end. I need to start over, but that is what i have

Tags: logic, formal-logic

I think my main issue is understanding if I am translating the negation of the statement correctly. I feel as if it is ultimately not logical when negated. Can someone please translate the first line please?

Exercise
6
.
3
7
.
In the following exercise, assess whether the indicated sentence is a logical truth in the blocks language. If so
,
use Fitch to construct a formal proof of the sentence from no premises
(
using Ana Con if necessary, but only applied to literals
)
.
If not, use Tarski
’
s World to construct a counterexample.
(
A counterexample here will simply be a world that makes the purported conclusion
[image]

Comment: Do you think the sentence is always true or not?

Comment: That is not a logical truth, so there is no point trying to prove it. If a is Eminem, b is Taylor Swift and c is Slim Shady, then you have a counterexample.

Comment: Isn't it true that 0 ≠ 1 AND 1 ≠ 0 AND 0 = 0? i.e. whenever c ≠ b, let c = a, and we have that the given statement is false.

Comment: Thank you all for your help and advice. I was able to see how it is not logical and create a counter example in tarski's. I really appreciate everyone's time on responding

Answer (score 1):

*Cogito* ...

(A = B) ∨(B = C) ∨¬(A = C)

Where do you see this kinda statement?
*Re cogito* .... There are *at **most** 2* (whatever).
∀x∀y∀z((Gx ⋀ Gy ⋀ Gz) ⊃ (x = y) ⋁ (y = z) ⋁ (x = z))

If you want to say *at **least** 2* (whatever) then,
∀x∀y∀z((Gx ⋀ Gy) ⊃ (x ≠ y))

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.

Comment: You're welcome @mechesad24.

Comment: @mechesad24, hadta make some corrections